# How do I get to know whether the URL is requested through Chrome browser or a Outlook Hyperlink in C#?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I want to filter out cases which are called through an outlook Hyperlink

Comment: You can't tell because email clients don't send that information. Web-based email used to send the `Referer` [sic] when links in emails were clicked but web-based email services now instruct browsers to not send the `Referer` header. This is to protect user's privacy and for security.

Comment: Check request headers, and work from there to identify, even if you don't get specific info, you can cluster them into groups.

Comment: @skjagini That won't work because web-based email services instruct browsers to not send the `Referer` header.

Answer (score 0):

You do not. Simple like that. In particular because your question makes no sense. If I configure Chrome to be my default browser, then if I open a hyperlink in Outlook it - will come as a request through chrome, so BOTH your conditions are fulfilled.

Comment: To be fair, I think they're asking if the original link in the email was opened from a desktop email client vs. web-based email services.

Comment: That is what I assume, too. Click in Outlook opening chrome with the URL.